# Symfony2 - DocumentChoiceList and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem when I'm trying to make a form with collections. I explain you what my current scenario is.

I've created two basic objects: **Product** and **Category**. And I've created two types for them as well: **ProductType, CategoryType**.

I have 3 categories and 1 product and I've associated the first couple of categories to the product. So, the product has two categories associated.

I want to create the Product's Form. In this form I want to show only the categories the product has, in a html select control, so the user can make future operations with these data.

I summarize you the key points.

1. My **Product** class has

   ```
   class Product 
   {
       ...

       @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Category")
       protected $categories;

       ...

   }
   ```
2. In my **ProductType** I have:

   ```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder->add('id')
           ->add('name')
           ->add('price')
           ->add('categories', 'document', array(
               'class' => 'Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Category',
               'choices' => $builder->getData()->getCategories()->toArray(),  
               'multiple' => 'true',
               'property' => 'name'                    
           ))
   ;
   ```

   }

I've tried with everything and the most accurate **half solution** was to create the **categories** property of the **ProductType** as a *document* and choose the options through the bind data come from the controller.

The point is, with this solution the **ids**, of the options controls, are the **spl_object_hash** set in the **UnitOfWork class**, not the **ids** of the original **Category object**.

My previous tryings:

1. I don't have problem when I use documents without previous choices, but I want only the categories that Product owns.
2. I don't have problem when I use a **collection** to show the list of categories (associating the **CategoryType**), but I don't know how to show this as a select control.
3. I can't use a **query_builder** over **Category class** because I can't query only the objects have the product id X, because **Category object** doesn't have any **Product reference** (and that's right).

Does anyone has a solution for this issue or other idea to solve this?

Thank you very much,
Ricky.

Answer (score 1):

you say

> I want to create the Product's Form. In this form I want to show only the categories the product has, in a html select control, so the user can make future operations with these data.

but then you go ahead and grab all the categories.

Why not keep things simple and grab the referenced categories off the product object?

```
$cats = $product->getCategories();     
if(!is_null($cats) && $cats->count() > 0) {
  $choices = $cats;
} else {
// grab all so you can have the use set them
  $choices = $builder->getData()->getCategories()->toArray()
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my later answer. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the problem. The problem is when you work with Embedded Documents in MongoDB.

When you're working with these kind of documents, Doctrine asume (with right logic) that you're not going to have a "manual" reference of this embedded document in other collection.

Yes, that seems logic, but... why can't you have a simplified embed document who references other extended version in other collection?. In my opinion, this is a mistake.

As I explained in my question, the ODM makes the id with a hash of the object not with ID anotation. So, you can grab all the options, as you point wisely, but your ids will be different to your Embed's ids.

Thank you again,
Ricky.